# html input type file accept image not allowing to choose file in ios 11

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, cordova, ios11

Upto ios 10 it was working. When user clicks on the input button in ipad it was asking to choose image from gallery or capture from camera. 
But in ios 11 it is directly opening the camera. Can any one please help me how to open gallery so that user can select image from gallery.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-input" capture />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this work with me

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-input"/>`

Comment: I tried with capture="camera" but still it is directly opening camera  but not gallery.

Comment: check it now  use filesystem

Comment: replaced with filesystem Still it is opening camera no option for gallery

Comment: add `multiple` and try cuz i dont have ios now

Comment: its working by removing capture. Thanks for your inputs. Your inputs helped me to fix the issue.